# Storing and serving course completion certificates for a small number of participants using Python (FastAPI)

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

What is the best approach for storing and serving course completion certificates for a small number of participants (80) using Python (FastAPI)? Should I store all the certificates in a database and provide them to users on request, or generate a new specific certificate on each request and store or delete it afterwards? Factors to consider may include performance, security, and maintenance.

As of now, I have stored all the course completion certificates in a database and am providing them to users upon request. However, I was wondering if it would be a better approach to generate a new certificate on each request, rather than generating all the certificates in advance and storing them. This would allow me to generate the certificate for each enrolled user and potentially save on storage space, but I am not sure if it would have any impact on performance or security. I am open to any suggestions or best practices for this type of system.

Comment: How are you storing in the database? Which database are you using?

Comment: i prefer try s3 or minio and before that produce and keep certificates to object storage then you already to answer users request.

Comment: @deadshot Currently I am using Postgres for storing all the certificates

Comment: @AshkanGolehPour sounds good but to use s3 I have to buy AWS which I cannot afford right now so currently I have Cpanel hosting and I am using that but thank you for your recommendation :)

Comment: your welcome.minio is free and easy to implement